# How many integer solutions to $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1,200,000$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to solve the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = n$ for $n = 1.2 \times 10^6 $

I have counted 131 solutions, which is certainly wrong.  I think:

$$ r_3( 1.2 \times 10^6) = r_3(2^7) \times r_3(3) \times r_3(5^6) $$

Certainly the middle one is easy:

$$ r_3(3) = 1 \text{ e.g. } 3 = 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2  $$

I don't know how many ways $n = 128$ or $n = 15625$ can be the sum of three squares.

Comment: Apparently this is very difficult, see this: https://mathoverflow.net/a/3645/57516

Comment: Anisotropic in 2-adic. Which means: as long as your number is divisible by $4,$ keep dividing by $4.$ Then do it.

Comment: Certainly $r_3$ is **not** a multiplicative function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of solutions $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ of $x^2+y^2=m$ is given by 
$$ 4\left(\chi_4 * 1\right)(m) = 4\sum_{d\mid m}\chi_4(d) = 4\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{\substack{d\mid m\\ d\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{4}}}\!\!\!\!\!1-4\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{\substack{d\mid m\\ d\equiv 3\!\!\pmod{4}}}\!\!\!\!\!1 $$
hence the number of solutions $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Z}^3$ of $x^2+y^2+z^2=1200000$ is given by

$$ 4(\chi_4*1)(1200000)+2\sum_{k=1}^{1095} 4(\chi_4*1)(1200000-k^2)=\color{red}{1488}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For any integer $x,$ $$x^2\equiv0,1\pmod4$$

So, $a,b,c$ must be even

Check for $\pmod3,\pmod5$

Answer (score 0):

1488....................................................

```
1471.      1040     344      -8
1472.      1040     344       8
1473.      1064    -248     -80
1474.      1064    -248      80
1475.      1064     -80    -248
1476.      1064     -80     248
1477.      1064      80    -248
1478.      1064      80     248
1479.      1064     248     -80
1480.      1064     248      80
1481.      1072    -200    -104
1482.      1072    -200     104
1483.      1072    -104    -200
1484.      1072    -104     200
1485.      1072     104    -200
1486.      1072     104     200
1487.      1072     200    -104
1488.      1072     200     104
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```